# Cannot parse value from xml to code libgdx

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, libgdx

I am trying parse data from an xml file to my libgdx game. My xml file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<levels currentLevel = "1">
    <Level1 speed="1" direction="1" lineAngle="14" />
    <Level2 speed="1" direction="1" lineAngle="14" />
    <Level3 speed="1" direction="1" lineAngle="14" />
</levels>
```

And the code I call in show method to take values from xml is:

```
XmlReader xml = new XmlReader();
    try {
        XmlReader.Element element = xml.parse(Gdx.files.internal("levels.xml"));
        XmlReader.Element root = element.getChildByName("levels");
        currentLevel = root.getInt("currentLevel");
        XmlReader.Element level = root.getChildByName("Level1");
        lineAngle = level.getInt("lineAngle");
        speed = level.getFloat("speed");
        direction = level.getInt("direction");
    }catch (Exception e){}
```

But I cannot get any value from xml. For example, I expect lineAngle to be 14 but it is 0. Can you explain to me why it is like this? And any solution would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you parse the file into element you are already at the root of your XML.
This works for me:

```
XmlReader xml = new XmlReader();
    try {
        // Element is the root element of your document, i.e. <levels>
        XmlReader.Element element = xml.parse(Gdx.files.internal("D:\\someFolder\\android\\assets\\levels.xml"));
        currentLevel = element.getInt("currentLevel");
        XmlReader.Element level = element.getChildByName("Level1");
        lineAngle = level.getInt("lineAngle");
        speed = level.getFloat("speed");
        direction = level.getInt("direction");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
```

I also had to give a complete path to levels.xml, e.g.: "D:\someFolder\android\assets\levels.xml"

Comment: at first, i tried the way you said, it didn't work. But now i deleted line that calls root element and instead of using getInt(), i used getattribute and cast it to integer, it works as i want. Thanks for your help.